# No gdm.css in Ubuntu 20.04, how to change login screen background then?

Tags: 20.04, login-screen, desktop-background

Before ubuntu 20.04 (at least in 18.04 I am sure) you could change the background for login screen, by editing /etc/alternatives/gdm.css, and changing the url of background image to my favourite file.
but there is no such file in 20.04
How could I do this in 20.04?

Comment: Oops! That supposed to answer my question but now after using that workaround number 2, I cannot login any more. In fact I see the login page, I enter my password, and I get this: oh no! Something has wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please logout and try again.

Comment: @MasoudBorbor can you press ctrl+alt+f3 or f4 or f5 etc.. and login there??

Comment: @PRATAP I did, and using tty I installed vanilla gnome (gnome-session gdm3) and  I logged in using that

Comment: thats a nice workaround you did.. I am sad if the script made you this problem.. may I know if you remember what coammand you did.. I mean `sudo ./focalgdm3 /absolute/path/to/Image` or someother.. and did you see success msg on terminal??

Comment: since you were able to see login page b4 the problem started.. was the background changed as per your choice?

Comment: @PRATAP np. I used this: sudo ./focalgdm3 /absolute/path/to/Image (and I did replace that with my "path to image" :D )
and I saw the success msg, after reboot I saw my favorite picture on Login screen (so it did work, though some fonts were weired and top icons like wifi, etc. was large and black) but unfortunately after I tried to login, I faced that problem

Comment: Ok.. seems there is a problem.. can you log on to tty and run `sudo ./focalgdm3 --reset` once you see reset successful msg.. reboot and choose default Ubuntu session.. if you would like to continue gnome-session ignore this comment..

Comment: Have you tried to make any tweakings related to theming with other scripts or something similar b4 doing the workaround 2??

Comment: @PRATAP I just mafe a backup of /etc/alternatives/gdm3-theme.gresource 
then tried another script wich was not successful (but after restoring and rebooting everything was fine)
and then I tried this one

Comment: @PRATAP before my last workaround (installing vanilla gnome) I tried that ./focalgdm3 --reset option. it said it is successful but the problem was still there.

Comment: Ok seems the backup you took is the keypoint.. I think another script you ran have an option to restore the original one.. if you go through that script you may manually find the correct backup one with ~ symbol.. anyway.. you need the original gresource file now.. I think you can get it by packages ubuntu or some --reinstall command.. once you did it.. the woraround 2 should work for you.. Thanks..

Comment: the moment you tried other script.. the changes it made are effective to `/etc/alternatives/xxx.resource` bcoz it is a symbolic file...